# run execution in a dfferent screen

Tags: maven

I have created a shell script with the below commands:

```
//sudo apt-get install xserver-xephyr(needed only for installation)

Xephyr -ac -screen 1280x1024 -br -reset -terminate 2> /dev/null :1 &
Xephyr -screen 1024x768 :51 &
export DISPLAY=:51
```

when this script runs, a different screen opens. After that if i run

```
mvn clean package
```

then it starts execution in this screen. so i can continue my work on my actual screen.

But problem is when i execute the script through pom.xml file, it then opens a screen but can not execute on that screen. It starts execution in my real screen.

My pom file to run the script is :

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <executions>
                    <execution><!-- Run our version calculation script -->
                        <id>Renaming build artifacts</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>bash</executable>
                            <commandlineArgs>/home/usr/test.sh</commandlineArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
        </plugin>
```

where is the problem? why my execution does not start on the opened screen by the script?
Or any other solution to run execution on different screen?

Thanks

Comment: You can't solve this problem from within Maven. Why not just call your shell script from the outside and let it open the new screen and trigger the maven build?

Comment: yes, if there is no way, i am planning to do so.